# Need a second pair of eyes to review my query

Tags: sql-server

```sql
INSERT INTO FAC_FACILITY (
    FACILITY_IDENTIFIER
    ,FACILITY_NAME
    ,FACILITY_TYPE_RID
    ,BUSINESS_START_DATE
    ,COMMENT_TEXT
    ,OPERATING_STATUS
    ,STATUS_CD
    ,CREATED_DATE
    ,CREATED_BY
    ,UPDATED_DATE
    ,UPDATED_BY
    ,VENDOR_IND
    )
SELECT Facility_Identifier
    ,Facility_name
    ,1
    ,BUSINESS_START_DATE
    ,COMMENT_TEXT
    ,OPERATING_STATUS
    ,'A'
    ,getdate()
    ,'sys'
    ,getdate()
    ,'sys'
    ,'T'
FROM STDB_beSQL.dbo.facility;

BEGIN
    DECLARE @ST_fac_iden VARCHAR(400)
        ,@ST_fac_rid VARCHAR(400)
        ,@address_rid INT;

    DECLARE facility_list_cur CURSOR
    FOR
    SELECT f.facility_rid
        ,f.FACILITY_IDENTIFIER
    FROM fac_facility f
    WHERE vendor_ind = 'T';

    OPEN facility_list_cur;

    BEGIN TRANSACTION

    BEGIN TRY
        FETCH NEXT
        FROM facility_list_cur
        INTO @ST_fac_rid
            ,@ST_fac_iden;

        WHILE @@fetch_status = 0
        BEGIN
            SET @address_rid = NEXT value
            FOR address_number;

            INSERT INTO sys_address (
                address_rid
                ,ADDRESS_LINE1
                ,CITY_NAME
                ,COUNTY_RID
                ,ZIP_CD
                ,STATUS_CD
                ,CREATED_BY
                ,UPDATED_BY
                ,CREATED_DATE
                ,UPDATED_DATE
                )
            SELECT @address_rid
                ,cast(ADDRESS_LINE1 AS VARCHAR(60))
                ,City_Name
                ,County_cd
                ,ZIP_CD
                ,'A'
                ,'sys'
                ,'sys'
                ,getdate()
                ,getdate()
            FROM STDB_beSQL.dbo.facility
            WHERE Facility_Identifier = @ST_fac_iden;

            INSERT INTO fac_address
            SELECT @ST_fac_rid
                ,@address_rid
                ,'A'
                ,getdate()
                ,'sys'
                ,getdate()
                ,'sys';

            INSERT INTO sys_physical_location (
                location_rid
                ,st_no
                ,ST_DIRECTION_RID
                ,ST_NAME
                ,CITY_NAME
                ,ZIP_CD
                ,county_rid
                ,STATUS_CD
                ,CREATED_BY
                ,UPDATED_BY
                ,CREATED_DATE
                ,UPDATED_DATE
                )
            SELECT @address_rid
                ,street_number
                ,CASE 
                    WHEN street_dir_cd = 'N'
                        THEN 1
                    WHEN street_dir_cd = 'S'
                        THEN 2
                    WHEN street_dir_cd = 'E'
                        THEN 3
                    WHEN street_dir_cd = 'W'
                        THEN 4
                    WHEN street_dir_cd = 'NE'
                        THEN 5
                    WHEN street_dir_cd = 'NW'
                        THEN 6
                    WHEN street_dir_cd = 'SE'
                        THEN 7
                    WHEN street_dir_cd = 'SW'
                        THEN 8
                    ELSE NULL
                    END
                ,street_name
                ,city_name
                ,ZIP_CD
                ,county_cd
                ,'A'
                ,'sys'
                ,'sys'
                ,getdate()
                ,getdate()
            FROM STDB_beSQL.dbo.facility
            WHERE Facility_Identifier = @ST_fac_iden;

            INSERT INTO fac_location
            SELECT @ST_fac_rid
                ,@address_rid
                ,'A'
                ,'sys'
                ,'sys'
                ,getdate()
                ,getdate();

            INSERT INTO sys_contact (
                contact_rid
                ,LAST_NAME
                ,FIRST_NAME
                ,COMPANY_NAME
                ,JOB_TITLE
                ,COMMENT_TEXT
                ,STATUS_CD
                ,CREATED_BY
                ,UPDATED_BY
                ,CREATED_DATE
                ,UPDATED_DATE
                )
            SELECT @address_rid
                ,last_name
                ,first_name
                ,COMPANY_NAME
                ,JOB_TITLE comment_text
                ,'A'
                ,'sys'
                ,'sys'
                ,getdate()
                ,getdate()
            FROM STDB_beSQL.dbo.facility
            WHERE Facility_Identifier = @ST_fac_iden;

            INSERT INTO fac_contact
            SELECT @ST_fac_rid
                ,@address_rid
                ,'A'
                ,getdate()
                ,'sys'
                ,getdate()
                ,'sys';

            INSERT INTO sys_telephonic (
                TELEPHONIC_RID
                ,PHONE_TYPE_RID
                ,PHONE_AREA_CODE
                ,PHONE_NO
                ,STATUS_CD
                ,CREATED_BY
                ,UPDATED_BY
                ,CREATED_DATE
                ,UPDATED_DATE
                )
            SELECT @address_rid
                ,1
                ,substring(phone_no, 1, 3)
                ,phone_no
                ,'A'
                ,'sys'
                ,'sys'
                ,getdate()
                ,getdate()
            FROM STDB_beSQL.dbo.facility
            WHERE Facility_Identifier = @ST_fac_iden;

            INSERT INTO fac_telephonic
            SELECT @ST_fac_rid
                ,@address_rid
                ,'A'
                ,getdate()
                ,'sys'
                ,getdate()
                ,'sys';

            INSERT INTO sys_contact_telephonic
            SELECT c.contact_rid
                ,@address_rid
                ,'A'
                ,'sys'
                ,'sys'
                ,getdate()
                ,getdate()
            FROM fac_contact c
            WHERE c.FACILITY_RID = @ST_fac_rid;

            INSERT INTO PMT_Permit (
                Permit_RID
                ,Permit_no
                ,facility_rid
                ,Issue_date
                ,STATUS_CD
                ,CREATED_BY
                ,UPDATED_BY
                ,CREATED_DATE
                ,UPDATED_DATE
                )
            SELECT @address_rid
                ,pemrit_id
                ,@ST_fac_rid
                ,Business_start_date
                ,'A'
                ,'sys'
                ,'sys'
                ,getdate()
                ,getdate()
            FROM STDB_beSQL.dbo.facility
            WHERE Facility_Identifier = @ST_fac_iden;

            FETCH NEXT
            FROM facility_list_cur
            INTO @ST_fac_rid
                ,@ST_fac_iden;
        END;

        COMMIT TRANSACTION;
    END TRY

    BEGIN CATCH
        IF @@trancount > 0
            ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;

        DECLARE @ErrorNumber INT = ERROR_NUMBER();
        DECLARE @ErrorLine INT = ERROR_LINE();
        DECLARE @ErrorMessage NVARCHAR(4000) = ERROR_MESSAGE();
        DECLARE @ErrorSeverity INT = ERROR_SEVERITY();
        DECLARE @ErrorState INT = ERROR_STATE();

        PRINT 'Actual error number: ' + CAST(@ErrorNumber AS VARCHAR(10));
        PRINT 'Actual line number: ' + CAST(@ErrorLine AS VARCHAR(10));

        RAISERROR (
                @ErrorMessage
                ,@ErrorSeverity
                ,@ErrorState
                );
    END CATCH;

    CLOSE facility_list_cur;

    DEALLOCATE facility_list_cur;
END;
```

Error:

> Msg 120, Level 15, State 1, Line 146
>   The select list for the INSERT statement contains fewer items than the insert list. The number of SELECT values must match the number of INSERT columns.

I did check all the insert into select  statement and seems perfect, but it still gives the error. Can anyone review it for me? Please let me if anything my eyes are missing to capture it.

Comment: @Richard Your exact close vote, and the fact this is totally off-topic on CR is exactly why you shouldn't "vote to close because it would be better at site xyz"... Please read [A Guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/5777/a-guide-to-code-review-for-stack-overflow-users)

Comment: My apology for not properly formatting the code .. I'm still new to this website.. I'm learning how to use the tool here.. next time i will more aware.. thank you for your comment and help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing a comma after `JOB_TITLE`, which causes SQL to treat `comment_text` as a column alias rather than as a column you want to select.  I have commented below where the comma needs to be added, from your original query (it's around line 146).

```
  select 
  @address_rid,
  last_name,
  first_name,
  COMPANY_NAME,
  JOB_TITLE --Right Here
  comment_text,
  'A',
    'sys',
   'sys',
  getdate(),
  getdate()
  from STDB_beSQL.dbo.facility
  where Facility_Identifier=@ST_fac_iden;
```